# MongoDB - Business hours, order by current day

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to recreate the Google "Hours" dropdown shown on a location listing.

[image]

A business hours array looks like this:

```
[
    {id: 5d991d1208ac396803a992ee, day: 'sunday', open: 560, close: 1050},
    {id: 5d991d1208ac396803a992ef, day: 'monday', open: 560, close: 1050},
    {id: 5d991d1208ac396803a992eg, day: 'tuesday', open: 560, close: 1050},
    {id: 45d991d1208ac396803a992e, day: 'wednesday', open: 560, close: 1050},
    {id: 5d991d1208ac396803a992eh, day: 'thursday', open: 560, close: 1050},
    {id: 5d991d1208ac396803a992eI, day: 'friday', open: 560, close: 1050},
    {id: 5d991d1208ac396803a992eG, day: 'saturday', open: 560, close: 1050},
]
```

So, if the current day was Tuesday I would like to return a sorted array like this :

```
[
    {id: 5d991d1208ac396803a992eg, day: 'tuesday', open: 560, close: 1050},
    {id: 45d991d1208ac396803a992e, day: 'wednesday', open: 560, close: 1050},
    ....
]
```

I'm using mongoose and MongoDB.

**UPDATE**
The IDs are generated by MongoDB so I can't sort them or match them.

Comment: Why you don't `$sort` with `id`?

Comment: please see update. Thanks

Comment: would it not be easier to design your model in such a way as to add the index of the day as an index or as a field to allow sorting? You don't always have to use mongoIDs. This is such a case. There will only ever be seven days in a week. But anyway, if you can't then yes, use Seoung Ho Jeoung's solution to sort the days of the week first then slice and concat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

slice and concatenate with spread operator:

```js
// needs the day of the week
// starting from Sunday as 0 and saturday as 6 since getDay()
// starts from 0
const currentDay = new Date().getDay() // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,  or 6

// here's your function

const getSortedArray = (arr) => [
  ...arr.slice(currentDay),
  ...arr.slice(0, currentDay)
]

// example

const days = [{
    id: '5d991d1208ac396803a992ee',
    day: 'sunday',
    open: 560,
    close: 1050
  },
  {
    id: '5d991d1208ac396803a992ef',
    day: 'monday',
    open: 560,
    close: 1050
  },
  {
    id: '5d991d1208ac396803a992eg',
    day: 'tuesday',
    open: 560,
    close: 1050
  },
  {
    id: '45d991d1208ac396803a992e',
    day: 'wednesday',
    open: 560,
    close: 1050
  },
  {
    id: '5d991d1208ac396803a992eh',
    day: 'thursday',
    open: 560,
    close: 1050
  },
  {
    id: '5d991d1208ac396803a992eI',
    day: 'friday',
    open: 560,
    close: 1050
  },
  {
    id: '5d991d1208ac396803a992eG',
    day: 'saturday',
    open: 560,
    close: 1050
  },
]

// ensure order of days
const daysSorted = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday']
  .map(day => days.filter(el => el.day === day)[0])

console.log(getSortedArray(daysSorted))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below aggregation

```
const day = "tuesday"

db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "data": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "data": 1,
    "days": {
      "$concatArrays": [
        {
          "$setDifference": [
            "$data.day",
            {
              "$slice": [
                "$data.day",
                { "$indexOfArray": ["$data.day", day] }  //Here you can replace the day with the current one
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "$slice": [
            "$data.day",
            { "$indexOfArray": ["$data.day", day] }  //Here you can replace the day with the current one
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$addFields": {
    "order": {
      "$indexOfArray": ["$days", "$data.day"]
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "order": 1 }},
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D0OAc3_xQdv)

Answer (score 0):

first sort business hours from mongodb data, then use Emmanuel N K's solution

```js
// needs the day of the week
const currentDay = new Date().getDay() // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 or  7

// here's your function
// subtract 1 from currentday since array indices start at zero

const getSortedArray= (arr) => [
    ...arr.slice(currentDay - 1), 
    ...arr.slice(0, currentDay - 1)
]

const getIntFromDay = (day) => {
    return ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday','saturday'].indexOf(day)
}

// example

const days = [
    {id: 5d991d1208ac396803a992ee, day: 'sunday', open: 560, close: 1050},
    {id: 5d991d1208ac396803a992ef, day: 'monday', open: 560, close: 1050},
    {id: 5d991d1208ac396803a992eg, day: 'tuesday', open: 560, close: 1050},
    {id: 45d991d1208ac396803a992e, day: 'wednesday', open: 560, close: 1050},
    {id: 5d991d1208ac396803a992eh, day: 'thursday', open: 560, close: 1050},
    {id: 5d991d1208ac396803a992eI, day: 'friday', open: 560, close: 1050},
    {id: 5d991d1208ac396803a992eG, day: 'saturday', open: 560, close: 1050},
]

sortedDays = days.sort((a, b) => {
    if(getIntFromDay(a.day) > getIntFromDay(b.day))
        return 1
    else
        return -1
})


console.log(getSortedArray(sortedDays))
```